# How to convert my ListView binding to x:Bind?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, xbind

Suppose I have the following source of sample data specified in my app:

**App.xaml:**

```
<sampleData:SampleUsers x:Key="SampleUsers"
        d:IsDataSource="True" />
```

How do I convert the following two bindings to their x:Bind variants ???

**UsersPage.xaml.**

```
xmlns:sampleData="using:MyApp.SampleData.SampleUsers"
.
.
.
<ListView DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleUsers}}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Users, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Expose `SampleUsers` from the code-behind of `UsersPage.xaml`:

   ```
   public SampleUsers SampleUsers => new SampleUsers();
   ```
2. Bind to it using `{x:Bind}` in the XAML:

   ```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind SampleUsers}" />
   ```

`{x:Bind}` does not use the `DataContext` as a default source — instead, it uses the page or user control itself as stated in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension). Also note that the default mode is `OneTime`, which is perfectly fine in this case assuming you don't reset the source property during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use x:bind, you could bind `ItemsSource` then declarex `x:DataType` for DataTemplate like the following.

```
<ListView  ItemsSource="{x:Bind SampleUsers.Users, Mode=OneWay}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:User">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Update**

You could define the `SampleUsers` in xaml page resource or code behind.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <sampleData:SampleUsers x:Key="SampleUsers"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

For more detail please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension).

Comment: Didn't work, it gives the error: "The property SampleUsers" was not found in type 'UsersPage' when I change the ItemsSource binding to your answer.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, the x:Bind will only see properties in the scope of the page and not from App.xaml?  Is that why it won't work?

Comment: @Maximus, I have updated the case reply, does it work?